# Invoke snowflake procedure from databricks pyspark or spark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, databricks-sql

Have to invoke a Snowflake stored procedure and pass the parameter value to it and then read the output.

This has to be achieved using Databricks pyspark something in below format lines.

```
df_sp= spark.sql()..('query','call sptest(1)');
```

The SP returns output as `Success` or `Failure`. This I have to read it from the variable `df_sp`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
%scala

// Scala has the ability to call a stored procedure at Snowflake. 
// Variables were set above

val SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils
if (vScaIsInc == "Yes"){
  var vScaSfOptions = Map(
    "sfUrl" -> vScaSfUrl,
    "sfUser" -> vScaSfUser,
    "sfPassword" -> vScaSfPassword,
    "sfDatabase" -> vScaSfDatabase,
    "sfSchema" -> vScafActualSchema,
    "sfWarehouse" -> vScaSfWarehouse,
    "usestagingtable" -> "OFF"
  )
  Utils.runQuery(vScaSfOptions, 'Call SP here (can also use variable) )
}
```